# How can I make the default value of an input changeable in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, input

I am new to working with React so this might be an easy one that I am struggling to figure out. Let's say I have this very simple class, that renders an input with a default value. I want this input to have the value I set it, but also being able to change it. However, when it renders, the input field is filled with "hi" and I can't write or delete anything over it. How can I make this possible?

```
export class Hello extends React.Component {
render(){
    let i = "hi"
    return(
        <div>
            <input type="input" value={i} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Store the input value as part of your component's state, and listen for the onchange event on the input field to update the component's state.

```
export class Hello extends React.Component {
  state = {
    textbox: "hi",
  };
  render() {
    return(
        <div>
            <input
              type="input"
              value={this.state.textbox}
              onChange={ev => this.setState({ textbox: ev.target.value })}
            />
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

See examples:  https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Answer (score 0):

You need to use state for this purposes. Look here: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Answer (score 0):

I'am adding a bit different answer, its depends if your component is Controlled or Uncontrolled component, see difference [in docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#controlled-vs-uncontrolled-components).

Controlled example you can find in other answers or [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components).

Uncontrolled example is usually when using `<form/>` elements, in this case you can just add `defaulValue` prop as mentioned in [related docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper).

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.input = React.createRef();
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.input.current.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input type="text" defaultValue="hi" ref={this.input} />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```